# _getch cohio.h c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

`int code = _getch;`
*Ошибка C2440   инициализация: невозможно преобразовать "int (__cdecl* *)(void)" в "int"*

### Что тут не так?

Comment: Вы не в Паскале :) Как в С++ **ВЫЗЫВАЕТСЯ** функция?

Comment: Еще раз - каков синтаксис вызова функции в С++? То, что вы делаете - это **НЕ** вызов функции.

Comment: как я же тупанул, спасибо

Comment: а как присвоить code label`y? ))

Comment: "Недопонял.... Перепроизнеси" (с) Что вы имеете в виду?

Comment: Как присвоить текст label от _getch

Comment: Читайте, собирайте, присваивайте... Только я что-то не пойму - у вас приложение консольное или оконное?

Comment: оконное приложение

Comment: Что не так?
C++ CodeDOM parser error: Line: 71, Column: 4 --- Unexpected token; scoping not allowed in this function
while (!_kbhit());
{
int code = _getch();
his->label1->Text = System::Int16(code).ToString();
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int code = _getch();
```

### Решил...)

Comment: Подобные вопросы лучше решать в чате. Тут их полно: https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=ru.stackoverflow.com